# Backlinking Many-To-1 relation in Xamarin.Forms using Realm

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm building an app using Xamarin.Forms with Realm as local database and I'm struggling with the following.

The app is consuming an API giving a JSON response like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5bf7029c-1577-4739-b37a-845cee1ef70d",
        "name": "Test",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "16db7cef-2f6a-4405-a004-df15864d4dde",
                "name": "Category 1",
                "master_id": "5bf7029c-1577-4739-b37a-845cee1ef70d",
                "rooms": [
                    {
                        "id": "d9246c9f-e8bb-41a9-b9a5-e21f1838de19",
                        "category_id": "16db7cef-2f6a-4405-a004-df15864d4dde",
                        "name": "Room 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "424a592d-8cb3-42a3-acbc-dc67d1ac8ddf",
                        "category_id": "16db7cef-2f6a-4405-a004-df15864d4dde",
                        "name": "Room 2",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have used QuickType to generate C# classes for me:

```
public class Master : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("categories")]
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("master_id")]
    public string MasterId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rooms")]
    public IList<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Room : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("category_id")]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With the help of Newtonsoft I am parsing the incoming JSON directly to objects and the database with the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Master> masters = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Master>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None

}));

realm.Write(() =>
{
    foreach (Master master in masters)
    {
        realm.Add(master);
    }
});
```

So far everything is working and the Master object including all child objects are created properly. However, I need to be able to access parent data easily. For instance, I want to be able to get the name of the Category when I only have a Room available using a statement like `Room.Category.Name`.

I have tried several way of achieving this but so far without success. I will elaborate on my attempts, because I have the feeling that I might be close.

My first attempt was by using the Realm Backlink property and added the following attribute to the Room class:

```
[Backlink(nameof(Category.Rooms))]
public Category Category { get; }
```

However, adding this property to the Room class results in this error:
`Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Room.Category' (CS0120)`.
If I look at the examples given on the Realm website, I only see examples in which the Backlink is placed on the parent class in stead of the child class what I am trying now, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

My second attempt was to have the relations populated by the JSON deserialization in reverse, so the Category would not contain a list of Rooms, but the Room would contain the Category (and I would be able to use the backlink as described in the examples that I found). However, only changing the C# models by adding the Category property to a Room and changing the Rooms property in the Category class to a backlink resulted in empty relations as the Category property was not populated at all. Maybe I should change the JsonSerializerSettings to 'enable' this feature, but I could not find any information if this is even possible.

My final attempt was to create a method that uses the CategoryId to give me the Category object from the Room object:

```
public Category Category
{
    get
    {
        return Realm.Find<Category>(CategoryId);
    }
}
```

While this seemed to work initially this approach is giving me errors when trying to use the Room.Category relation in queries to Realm (using Linq) as the relation cannot be processed by Realm. I also get a warning when building the app: `Warning: Fody/RealmWeaver: Room.Category is not an automatic property but its type is a RealmObject which normally indicates a relationship.`

Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Backlink properties are always collections because nothing prevents you from adding the same room to two different categories. That is why in most examples they are placed on the "parent" class. Still, you could easily add one on the "child" class if you're certain it'll only belong to a single parent:

```
public class Room : RealmObject
{
    // Other properties

    // Notice that the collection may be private
    // to avoid polluting your public API
    [Backlink(nameof(Category.Rooms))]
    private IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; }

    // May also use FirstOrDefault if you can't guarantee
    // the room will be added to a single Category
    public Category Category => Categories.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Keep in mind that you still won't be able to use `Category` in LINQ expressions because it's not a persisted property that Realm is aware of.